# Replace a value with a variable from flowfile using apache-nifi

Tags: csv, replace, apache-nifi

I am trying to replace a value with a variable assigned in flowfile.

In my flowfile, I have assigned `flowID` to `flow_id` variable.

In `UpdateRecord` processor, I try to update a column named `/flow` which has `INFLOW` and `OUTFLOW` I have following as `${field.value:replaceAll('INFLOW',$flow_id)}`

Flowfile before `UpdateRecord`:

```
id,flow,flow_id
1,INFLOW,IN
2,OUTFLOW,OUT
3,INFLOW,IN
```

After the conversion flowfile should be:

```
id,flow,flow_id
1,IN,IN
2,OUT,OUT
3,IN,IN
```

But it fails with an error

> unexpected token

Edit : After answer and comments

Now I have following settings:

`${field.value:replace('INFLOW',flow_id)}`

> Due to unexpected token `flow_id`

Same error for `Literal Value` and `Record path value` Replacement strategies.

Comment: The second `$` unnecessary.

Comment: @daggett I have tried `{flow_id}` and `flow_id`  , but still `unexpected token`

Comment: What is the replacement strategy value?

Comment: @daggett I have used both `Record Path Value` and `Literal Value`.

Comment: With Literal Value this should work if you defined attribute with name `flow_id` for the flow file: `${field.value:replace('INFLOW',flow_id)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set up the Nifi Workflow as shown below :**

[image]

Set your `input directory` in the `GetFile` Processor. In the first `UpdateRecord` Processor concatenate the `flow` and `flow_id` columns and assign it into `flow`. Do this by changing the configurations of the **First** `UpdateRecord` processor as shown below.

[image]

The next `UpdateRecord` Processor replaces `INFLOW` and `OUTFLOW` accordingly. Set the configurations of the **second** `UpdateRecord` Processor as shown below.

[image]

Because of the initial concating `"` and `,` is added in the flow column. I have used the other two processors to remove them.

The **third** `UpdateRecord` Processor must have a new property named `/flow` and have the value `${field.value:replaceFirst(${field.value:substringAfter(',')},'')}`. The rest of the configurations remain as the **Second** `UpdateRecord` Processor.

The **Fourth** `UpdateRecord` Processor must have a new property named `/flow` and have the value `${field.value:replaceFirst('"',''):replaceFirst(',','')}`. The rest of the configurations remain as the **Second** `UpdateRecord` Processor.

**Note:** This answer was ***based on the concepts*** used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047115/add-two-columns-together-using-apache-nifi).

Comment: A bit long solution, but solved the issue. For now I accept this as the answer as it solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

**This Answer is for Attribute substitution.**  OP actually wants to replace the column values from the other column values.

---

From the documentation, you can find the detailed usage of the variables and parameters.

- For the variables, see [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Using_Custom_Properties)
- For the parameters, see [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Parameters)

When you use a **Variable** such as

- Processor-specific attributes
- FlowFile properties
- FlowFile attributes
- From Variable Registry:

  - User defined properties (custom properties)
  - System properties
  - Operating System environment variables

You can refer the variable such as:

```
${name of variable}
```

When you use a **parameter** from the parameter context, you can refer the parameter such as:

```
#{name of parameter}
```

In your case, you want to use a variable and so it should be:

```
${field.value:replaceAll('INFLOW',${flow_id})}
```

I have tested with the csv data,

```
index,flow
1,INFLOW
2,OUTFLOW
3,INFLOW
```

and the attribute `flow_id` with the value `'flowId'`. Now, I have set the `UpdateRecord` processor with the options as follows:

```
Record Reader                  CSVReader
Record Writer                  CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy     Literal Value
/flow                          ${field.value:replace('INFLOW', ${flow_id})}
```

The output csv is as expected.

```
index,flow
1,flowID
2,OUTFLOW
3,flowID
```

Comment: This answer is confusing variables with parameters. Expression language which can reference variables, flow file attributes, system props, and env vars uses ${ } . Parameters which is a new feature and only references parameters, uses #{ }.

Comment: `Unexpected Tocken <EOF>`

Comment: If you want to use field.value or variable, the option of UpdateRecord should be `Literal Value`. Or use replace not replaceAll.

Comment: The problem is still going on, please update your question in more detail, I will do my best.

Comment: @Lamanus **failed to process standard flowfile record will route to null** , as I have showed, `flow_id` is another column in the flowfile. not a predefined value.

Comment: If `flow_id` is a different column value, you cannot do it in this way. I will think more about this.

Comment: @Lamanus exactly, this is what I want to do. I will replace current value with another column data and then have to perform many actions on that.
Another question which is related to this is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047115/add-two-columns-together-using-apache-nifi

Comment: Yeap, but your example just replace the column flow_id to flow, that is easy. If there are complex conditions, then you have to split each record and do some logic, merge again that is the only way I think.