# Add two columns together using apache-nifi

Tags: postgresql, variables, apache-nifi, flowfile

I have following scenario. I one database table I have :

```
| id | name | basic_salary | allowance |
_______________________________________|
| 1  | sach | 2000         | 1000      |
| 2  | nala | 5000         | 2500      |
|______________________________________|
```

add `basic_salary` and `allowance` togther and making it as `net_salary` and insert to a new table called `net_salary`

For first step, I used `ExecuteSQLRecord` processor and can get all the records. But problem is : How to add those two columns coming in flowfile.

So final result should be :

```
| id | name | net_salary |
|________________________|
| 1  | sach | 3000       |
| 2  | nala | 7500       |
```

This is directly related to [my previous variable question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974062/replace-a-value-with-a-variable-from-flowfile-using-apache-nifi/58976236#58976236). 
How to handle flowfile variables to perform operations in `apache-nifi`?

I used [How to compute the sum of multiple columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719557/how-to-compute-the-sum-of-multiple-columns-in-postgresql) inside `ExecuteSQL` processor, but it can not understand flowfile variables.

Comment: When you execute sql, query by sum two columns.

Comment: @Lamanus `SELECT COALESCE(basic_salary,0) + COALESCE(allowance,0)1` Error is : **column basic_salary does not exitis**

Comment: check by using double quotes in your columns.

Comment: @natarajank **Unable to execute SQL query** , My SQL : `SELECT COALESCE("basic_salary",0) + COALESCE("allowance",0)`

Comment: SELECT "column" FROM FLOWFILE. did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tricky one. Use `UpdateRecord` twice.

The first one is

```
Record Reader               CSVReader
Record Writer               CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy  Record Path Value
/net_salary                 concat(/basic_salary, ',', /allowance)
```

and the second one is

```
Record Reader               CSVReader
Record Writer               CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy  Literal Value
/net_salary                 ${field.value:substringBefore(','):toNumber():plus(${field.value:substringAfter(','):toNumber()})}
```

where it gives the result as follows.

```
id,name,basic_salary,allowance,net_salary
1,sach,2000,1000,3000
2,nala,5000,2500,7500
```