# Concatinate two values removing null using apche-nifi

Tags: csv, replace, apache-nifi

I have following scenario. 
In first flowfile, I have :

```
id,name,sms,call
1,sachith,,07121
2,nalaka,039444,
3,john,04954,
4,malcom,,69595
```

Then I concatinate `sms` and `call` columns together to a new column called `operator` using `UpdateRecord` processor. [Inspired from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047115/add-two-columns-together-using-apache-nifi/59067443#59067443)

```
Replacement Value Strategy  Record Path Value
/operator                 concat(/sms, ',', /call)
```

New flow file is :

```
id,name,sms,call,operator
1,sachith,,07121,"null,07121"
2,nalaka,039444,,"039444,null"
3,john,04954,,"04954,null"
4,malcom,,69595,"null,,69595"
```

In next `UpdateRecord` processor, I try to remove this `null` and make it into a single value. For that I use (need to modify):

```
Replacement Value Strategy  Literal Value
/operator                   ${field.value:replaceFirst('null',${field.value:substringBefore(',')})}
```

Output of this is :

```
id,name,sms,call,operator
1,sachith,,07121,"null,07121"
2,nalaka,039444,,"039444,039444"
3,john,04954,,"04954,04954"
4,malcom,,69595,"null,69595"
```

What I want to do is simply remove all these `null` and replace with the `number`

```
id,name,sms,call,operator
1,sachith,,07121,07121
2,nalaka,039444,,039444
3,john,04954,,04954
4,malcom,,69595,69595"
```

Do I have to use any other processor other than `UpdateRecord`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way with `UpdateRecord` processor which have the options,

```
Record Reader                 CSVReader
Record Writer                 CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy    Record Path Value
/operator                     concat(/sms[isEmpty(/call)], /call[isEmpty(/sms)])
```

This will give you the result as follows:

```
id,name,sms,call,operator
1,sachith,,07121,07121
2,nalaka,039444,,039444
3,john,04954,,04954
4,malcom,,69595,69595
```

If both are not null, then they will be concatenated and if both are null, the result will also be null.

Comment: Work as expected from one `UpdateRecrod` processor.

Comment: Quite elegant, the only thing I would expect to keep in mind is that if both are non-null it presumably concatenates without comma