# Handling numeric operations in Nifi UpdateRecord using record path

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

I am using UpdateRecord Processor in Nifi where I need to get value from one record path (/amount), add some value to it and put the resulting value to another record path (/result).
I could not find any way of doing this. Any help would be great!!

[image: UpdateRecord Screenshot]

Comment: what did you mean with : "get value from one record path" ?

Comment: I mean using numeric operations on one record path and storing it in another record path

Answer (score 0):

Use `UpdateRecord` twice.

The first one is

```
Record Reader               CSVReader
Record Writer               CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy  Record Path Value
/result                     /amount
```

and the second one is

```
Record Reader               CSVReader
Record Writer               AvroRecordSetWritter
Replacement Value Strategy  Literal Value
/result                     ${field.value:toNumber():plus(1000)}
```

where the answer is based on my the other answer, [Add two columns together using apache-nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047115/add-two-columns-together-using-apache-nifi/59067443#59067443)